# Tell Doctrine to use different MySQL users based on use

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Fairly simple question really, but is there any way at all, to get Doctrine (when using Symfony's console) to use a different database user than the ones provided in the parameters?

**Edit**

Was suggested I explain myself.

I have modified Symony2 to use 2 different MySQL users based on context 4 ways.  I have two bundles, a Core and an Administration bundle. The modification is that the database user located in the Core bundle only needs Read access privileges to the database, while Administration also has reduced privileges, but can Insert, Update, and Delete records.

This is accomplished by using Symfony's regular expression based url matching (administration is a totally different URL, not just a /admin). So I have configurations for Development Environment on the two local url's, and for Production for the two local url's.

As mentioned, even administration has reduced privileges, entirely for security reasons. I do not want that database user to be able to alter tables or change schemas.

On Development environment, database users are given full privileges of course

Right now, when I run Doctrine Migrations and Schema updates on Production, I have to manually adjust the given database user elevated privileges and then revoke them while I do my business.

I would simply like the console version of doctrine to use a third user that has slightly more elevated privileges.

Comment: not without creating a new connection for that user. Unusual request, if you explained why you wanted it an alternative could probably be suggested.

Comment: @Dagon added the explanation for ya

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but you could have Doctrine connect to completely different databases, using different users, and on different hosts, depending on whether you're in the development or production environment.

To do so:

1. Open your `config.yml` and locate this section

   ```
   doctrine:
       dbal:
           # Remove from here
           driver:   "%database_driver%"
           host:     "%database_host%"
           port:     "%database_port%"
           dbname:   "%database_name%"
           user:     "%database_user%"
           password: "%database_password%"
           # Stop here
   ```
2. Delete the lines where I've marked in the comments. You'll want to keep the `doctrine` and `dbal` lines so other Doctrine settings are preserved in the lower lines.
3. Open `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml` and add the following

   ```
   doctrine:
       dbal:
           driver:   "pdo_mysql"
           host:     "your_host_here (usually localhost)"
           port:     "3306"
           dbname:   "db_name_here"
           user:     "db_user_here"
           password: "db_password_here"
   ```

Replace values appropriately for each file. Then you can run `php app/console` commands using the `--env=prod` and `--env=dev` flags. You will also be connected to different databases when you use `app.php` and `app_dev.php`, respectively.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm that last line may be the key.   running commands with `--env=`